# How to make AJAX request to EC2 on AWS, login/password needed

Tags: javascript, ajax, python-3.x, amazon-ec2

I have some `javascript` sending GET request to a `python` server. It's all been good when I run the server on `localhost`. Like this:

**js**:

```
$.get({
    url: 'http://localhost:7973/loadPage',
    success: function(result){pageLoadSucceed(result);},
    error: function(error){requestFailed(error);}
});
```

**python**:

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/loadPage', LoadPageHandler)
    ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(7973)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Now, I moved the service to an EC2 Windows Server on AWS. The service still launches fine. However, when I making requests from my machine with the code below, it fails (timeout).

**modified js**:

```
$.get({
    url: 'http://Administrator:eX%f4TYtaJLu*YCdt$Nm;le7$tmfqLv3@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7973/loadPage',
    success: function(result){pageLoadSucceed(result);},
    error: function(error){requestFailed(error);}
});
```

Since in browser (chrome), the same url gives me an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, I assume my url is wrong.

But I am just not sure how it is wrong - is one of the ingredients (address, username, password) is wrong or did I piece them together wrong? The ingredients I got from the AWS page after clicking "Connect" as shown below:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you pull up the same url in a browser w/o problems? if so, it's CORS. If not, the url/server is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @dandavis, I can't pull anything in the browser either. I am pretty sure I constructed the url wrong. That is my question. Let me break my question down to be more explicit.